# JQuery. Accessing Elements in the DOM below and object

Tags: jquery-selectors

I'm using an API that returns a JQuery Object which is a reference to a DIV container. I know my structure inside of the DIV container. I basically need to read some attributes from the first .
I've tried chaining the standard selectors off of my object but I get an error.

> XML filter is applied to non-XML value ({selector:"div.panes > div.slice(0,1)", context:({}), 0:({}), length:1})
>   [Break on this error] var svideo = $(api.getCurrentPane()).('a').get(0);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to use [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) when you're going for descendant elements, like this for the DOM element reference directly:

```
$(api.getCurrentPane()).find('a').get(0)
//or..
$(api.getCurrentPane()).find('a')[0]
```

or if you want a jQuery object...

```
$(api.getCurrentPane()).find('a:first')
//or..
$(api.getCurrentPane()).find('a:eq(0)')
//or..
$(api.getCurrentPane()).find('a').eq(0)
```